# Segmentation fault when allocating large arrays on the stack

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

When I compiled this simple C code it's fine but after uncommenting the line it shows segmentation fault. I don't know what's wrong with this. Please help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
    {
    int arr[10002][10002];
    int color[10002];
    int neigh;
 // scanf("%d",&neigh);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you probably have... *drum roll* ...a **Stack Overflow** ! *rimshot*

Comment: which number are you typing in?

Comment: I think is a problem, allocating memory for many elements for the array int arr. And you have reached the limit. Obviously it depends also from the OS you are using. Read this link : http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/131385-maximum-size-array

Answer (score 12):

You're blowing the stack with `arr` and `color`. Presumably when your call to `scanf` is commented out the compiler optimises all these variables away, but when it's present it attempts to allocate memory on the stack.

Make the variables global, and read up on stack memory vs heap memory.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int arr[10002][10002];
int color[10002];

int main()
{
    int neigh;
    scanf("%d",&neigh);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Variables allocated inside a function are put on the stack, which has a limited size.  You can allocate them on the (larger) heap instead by using `malloc`.

Comment: oops!  '... by using "malloc."'